# How to remove smaller repeating substring of string efficiently?

Tags: java

Consider

```
String example = "year, year - 1970, year - 1980, event, event - launch, event - stop, event - stop - final, 1970 - year"
```

which represent top-category, mid-category, low-category.
How to remove everything, but most expanded distinct categories? E.g:

```
"year" - occurs as first element in "year - 1970" and  "year - 1980", so it is removed.
"event" - occurs in "event - launch", "event - stop", "event - stop - final", so it is removed.
"event - stop" occurs in "event - stop - final", so it is removed.
```

Result should be:

```
example = "year - 1970, year - 1980, event - launch, event - stop - final, 1970 - year"
```

My attempt is very slow

```
String[] part = example.split(",");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : part) {
  list.add(s);
}
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    if (list.get(j).contains(list.get(i))) {
      String[] split1 = list.get(j).split("-");
      String[] split2 = list.get(i).split("-");
      if (split2.length < split1.length) list.remove(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why `event, event - launch, event - stop, event - stop - final` becomes `event - launch, event - stop - final`?

Comment: @JasonZ its 2 distinct branches. `event - stop` is subsctring of `event - stop - final` and thus removed. `event - launch` does not have any expancion, so it is kept

Comment: Show the code of your attempt at a solution or at least an algorithm in words. This is not a coding service.

Comment: @user1803551 updated, but my solution is too slow

Comment: What you want is to find all leaf nodes of a tree. I suggest you look into an algorithm that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test application.  Here are the results.

```
input     year, year - 1970, year - 1980, event, event - launch, event - stop, 
          event - stop - final, 1970 - year
output    year - 1970, year - 1980, event - launch, event - stop - final, 1970 - year
```

I split the input line using `", "`.  I used the String `startsWith` method to edit out the higher categories.

Here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class RemoveSubstrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "year, year - 1970, year - 1980, event, "
                + "event - launch, event - stop, event - stop - final, "
                + "1970 - year";
        System.out.println(example);
        System.out.println(substring(example));
    }

    public static String substring(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split(", ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            boolean unique = true;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < parts.length; j++) {
                if (parts[j].startsWith(parts[i])) {
                    unique = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (unique) {
                builder.append(parts[i]);
                builder.append(", ");
            }
        }

        if (builder.length() > 2) {
            return builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 2).toString();
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```